# Possible quotient subgroups of $\mathbb Z^2$

Tags: group-theory

The question is as follow

> Let $A\cong \mathbb Z^2$
>
> Is there a $B \lt A$ such that $A/B \cong \mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/21\mathbb Z$ ?
>
> Is there a $C \lt A$ such that $A/C \cong \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/14\mathbb Z$ ?

I really have no sense of idea how to approach this using the theorems I've learned. any help will be appreciated!

Comment: For the first one, it might help if you notice that $Z/3Z \times Z/5Z \cong Z/15Z$. For the second, $A/C$ has a quotient isomorphi to $C_2^3$, which cannot be generated by two elements.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand why $A/C$ has a quotient isomorphic to $C_{2}^3$?

Comment: It is a very easy result that the cyclic group $C_n$ of order $n$ has $C_m$ as a subgroup and as a quotient if and only if $m$ divides $n$.

Comment: Yes got it thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Since $A$ has two generators, any quotient of $A$ can also be generated by at most $2$ elements. At the same time, if you have an abelian group $G$ that can be generated by $2$ elements $g_1, g_2$ (which may be equal), there is a surjective homomorphism form $A$ to $G$ by sending two generators of $A$ to $g_1$ and $g_2$, respectively.

Comment: @lhf could you elaborate?

Comment: @KimSeel If there is a homomorphism $f$ from an abelian group (like our $A$) into $G$ such that $g_1$ and $g_2$ are both in the image of $f$ (say $f(a_1)=g_1,f(a_2)=g_2$), then $g_1$ and $g_2$ commute, because$$g_1g_2=f(a_1)f(a_2)=f(a_1a_2)=f(a_2a_1)=f(a_2)f(a_1)=g_2g_1$$If $f$ is surjective, then every element is in the image, so every pair of elements has to commute, which means that $G$ is abelian. I could specify that $G$ is abelian in my answer (like I did), or I could be more specific and say that $g_1$ and $g_2$ commute (which implies that $G$ is abelian).

Comment: Either way, doing neither (which was what my answer did originally) is wrong, and lhf rightfully corrected me.

Comment: what you said is known to me. from what I understand is that I need to show that there are up 2 generators in each quotient. I can show that the first is $A/B \cong \mathbb Z/15\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z / 21 \mathbb Z$. I'm not entirely sure about $A/C$ and I don't understand the point you're trying to make, sorry.

Comment: You won't be able to find a set of two generators for $A/C$, and my first sentence tells you then that it cannot be a quotient of $A$. The rest of my answer will help you proving that $A/B$ is possible, by helping you look for a concrete $B$.